# Convert MPG file into frames

Tags: c#

I need to convert a video (MPG if possible) into frames using C#.

Is there any fast way to do so, using C# classes?

Comment: The fastest way it to delegate to `ffmpeg`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use theses libraries, it's very interessant

http://www.ffmpeg.org/

http://ffmpegdotnet.codeplex.com/